# Invalid Token when reset password using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, satellizer

I use Satellizer with Laravel for Authentication and I have a table on my db called password_resets with the following fields: id, email, token, I am able to submit a reset link and add the token into this table, but when it comes to change the password it returns Invalid Token.

Just so you know,I am not quite sure and I dont even believe it, how is this possible the problem occurs only when the number of rows on the password_resets table goes above 30-40, for ex if I delete all records than it works fine...Quite strange!

My backend code looks as below:

```
public function postReset(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only(
            'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );

        $response = $this->passwords->reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
            $user->password = bcrypt($password);

            $user->save();

            $this->auth->login($user);
        });


        switch ($response) {
            case PasswordBroker::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return Response::json(array('success' => true));

            default:
                return Response::json(array('success' => false, 'message' => $response));
        }
    }
```

So it always goes into the default stm with a message of Invalid Token.

Comment: how is the token passed to the user?

Comment: @SanzeebAryal via email

Comment: @Lulzim Fazlija I have same problem if you have solution, please let me konw